# Custom authentication provider with @Component

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

While using spring security, I have encountered a weird issue that I am not able to wrap my head around.
If I declare a custom authentication provider with the `@Component` annotation, Spring is no longer able to detect the authentication provider for `BasicAuthenticationFilter`. I am passing both the basic auth and the key for my custom filter in the headers using postman. This is the exception/error:

```
2024-02-26T01:56:59.981+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/public/**'], Filters=[]] (1/2)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.981+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@409df37d, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@2ab1c7a9, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@22c14d10, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@e594c46, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@27b7913, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@411e567e, com.prajwal.security.config.filter.CustomFilter@7cfb4736, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@5257123d, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@38276668, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3344c1d7, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@6e818345, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@5dd5422f, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@339b45f8]] (2/2)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.981+05:30 DEBUG 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing GET /private/hello
2024-02-26T01:56:59.981+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.981+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Did not protect against CSRF since request did not match CsrfNotRequired [TRACE, HEAD, GET, OPTIONS]
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking LogoutFilter (6/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            : Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout', POST]
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CustomFilter (7/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (8/13)
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 TRACE 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Found username 'prajwal' in Basic Authorization header
2024-02-26T01:56:59.982+05:30 DEBUG 4304 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  : Failed to process authentication request

org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderNotFoundException: No AuthenticationProvider found for org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:234) ~[spring-security-core-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:174) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at com.prajwal.security.config.filter.CustomFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomFilter.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.5.jar:6.1.5]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.14.jar:6.0.14]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:340) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:896) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1744) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-10.1.16.jar:10.1.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583) ~[na:na]
```

**CustomAuthentication.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class CustomAuthentication implements Authentication {

    private final boolean isAuthenticated;
    private final String key;

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return List.of(() -> "USER");
    }

    @Override
    public Object getCredentials() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getDetails() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getPrincipal() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAuthenticated() {
        return this.isAuthenticated;
    }

    @Override
    public void setAuthenticated(boolean isAuthenticated) throws IllegalArgumentException { }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object another) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return "CustomAuthentication";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean implies(Subject subject) {
        return Authentication.super.implies(subject);
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationProvider.java**

```java
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Value("${our.key}")
    private String key;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        CustomAuthentication ca = (CustomAuthentication) authentication;

        String headerKey = ca.getKey();
        if(null != headerKey && headerKey.equals(key)) {
            return new CustomAuthentication(true, null);
        }
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return CustomAuthentication.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication);
    }
}
```

**CustomAuthenticationManager.java**

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {

    private final CustomAuthenticationProvider cap;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if(cap.supports(authentication.getClass())) {
            return cap.authenticate(authentication);
        }

        return authentication;
    }
}
```

**CustomFilter.java**

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final CustomAuthenticationManager cam;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        CustomAuthentication ca = new CustomAuthentication(false, request.getHeader("key"));
        Authentication authentication = cam.authenticate(ca);

        SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();
        securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

        SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig.java**

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final CustomFilter customFilter;

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/public/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeHttpRequests(authorizeConfig -> {
                    authorizeConfig.anyRequest().authenticated();
                })
                .httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .addFilterBefore(customFilter, BasicAuthenticationFilter.class);

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }
}
```

**JpaUserDetailsService.java**

```java
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class JpaUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) {
        System.out.println("UserDetailsService is called");
        User user = userRepository.findByName(username);
        System.out.println("User: " + user.getUsername() + " accessed the pages");
        return new SecurityUser(user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to reproduce the issue locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** When using Spring Security:

- In general, do not implement your own `AuthenticationManager` unless you have very complex use-cases
- Do not expose *exactly one* `AuthenticationProvider` as a `@Bean` or `@Component`. It gets precedence over auto-configuration, and prevents any  `UserDetailsService` from being configured into an authentication provider.

Explanations are below, as well as a suggestion for your particular use-case.

---

### Suggestions for your use-case

1. Drop `CustomAuthenticationManager`. You should not need this.
2. Keep the `CustomAuthentication`
3. The `CustomFilter` may need little more logic around what happens if the key is not present. Do you really want to try and authenticate the request, or should you delegate to other authentication mechanisms? For example:

```java
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CustomFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final AuthenticationManager cam;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
        if (request.getHeader("key") == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

4. If the above seems correct, you probably need to build use an AbstractHttpConfigurer to pass the `AuthenticatonManager` to your `CustomFilter`. There is [an example in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/configuration/java.html#jc-custom-dsls)
5. [ **MOST IMPORTANTLY**] Your `CustomAuthenticationProvider` is fine, but DO NOT make it a `@Component`. Put it as a simple object your security configuration instead:

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig {

    private final CustomFilter customFilter;

    @Bean
    public WebSecurityCustomizer webSecurityCustomizer() {
        return web -> web.ignoring().requestMatchers("/public/**");
    }

    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                // ...
                .authenticationProvider(new CustomAuthenticationProvider());

        return http.build();
    }

    // ...
}
```

---

### Explanations

#### Custom AuthenticationManager

Usually it is not a good idea to implement your own instead of relying on the defaults. You will be missing a lot of the features of the `ProviderManager` and potentially `ObservationAuthenticationManager`. What you want to do is to create your own `AuthenticationProvider` and make sure it is used.

Additionally, creating the `AuthenticationManager` as a `@Bean` / `@Component` does nothing. It must be configured explicitly in the HttpSecurity config, like so:

```java
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http
                .authenticationManager(new MyAuthenticationManager())
                // ...
                .build();
    }
```

#### AuthenticationProvider as `@Bean` / `@Component`

In Spring Security, when you use `@EnableWebSecurity`, a "global" `AuthenticationManager` is created for you through the [HttpSecurityConfiguration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4d039e515fd98be0fc0e4c9be34aa891f71a7dce/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/HttpSecurityConfiguration.java#L109).

By default, it will use any `UserDetailsService` you have provided as a bean, as hinted [in the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/passwords/index.html#customize-global-authentication-manager) (emphasis mine):

> **Normally, Spring Security builds an AuthenticationManager internally composed of a DaoAuthenticationProvider for username/password authentication**. In certain cases, it may still be desired to customize the instance of AuthenticationManager used by Spring Security. For example, you may need to simply disable credential erasure for cached users.

This happens through [InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4d039e515fd98be0fc0e4c9be34aa891f71a7dce/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/InitializeUserDetailsBeanManagerConfigurer.java).

**HOWEVER**, if you provide *exactly one* `@Bean` / `@Component` of type `AuthenticationProvider`, like in your example, then another configuration kicks in, [InitializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4d039e515fd98be0fc0e4c9be34aa891f71a7dce/config/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/authentication/configuration/InitializeAuthenticationProviderBeanManagerConfigurer.java), which takes precedence over the user-details config mentioned above. Note that if you have *zero* or *two or more* components of type `AuthenticationProvider`, the UserDetails configuration does work as expected. This is not documented AFAIK.

Comment: Thanks, for the explanation. Weird behavior but I tried specifying two custom authentication providers using @Component to test it out(as you said: "if you provide exactly one @Bean / @Component of type `AuthenticationProvider`, like in your example, then another configuration kicks in"), and it works !!. What might be the logic behind implementing such a functionality, that specifying zero or more than one works ?

Comment: Glad it helped! 

Although it does work, I recommend avoiding _two_ `AuthenticationProvider`s just to avoid the configuration problems, if one day one is removed then the problem would come back ; instead use the suggested approach of "normal" instances instead of beans :)

I do not know why it was originally like this. Changing this would be a major breaking change at this point, so there is probably little appetite to do so.